# Graphing or charting in windows mobile 6

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, charts, graph

Do you know of a [free] library for graphing or charting, similar to Zedgraph, but that works for developing on windows mobile 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A basic, free chart API is http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/pocketbargraph.aspx

If web access and bandwidth are not a problem, http://code.google.com/apis/chart/ might be an (admittedly unconventional) option.

Regards, tamberg

Comment: thanks, we will give it a try.. we were considering using the web to show the graph using open flash chart (http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/) but web access and bandwidth are a issue

Comment: We used the codeproject.com API that provides a "graph motor".. works nicely and I recommend using it for simple bar graphs.

Comment: @GeriesHandal's link is now broken. [I think this is the new url](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12448/Simple-Bar-Chart-for-Pocket-PC)

Answer (score 0):

I once used a listbox to create a (horizontal) bar graph. I needed to catch a paint event for the listbox items to be able to draw the bars. Not easy, but free if your time is free...

Comment: well trying not to reinvent the wheel